# jQuery code strange acting

Tags: jquery

Ok i have a code like this :

```
function swapImages() {  
    $('.recipeImages').each(function() {  
        if($('li.active', this).length == 0) {  
        $('li:first', this).fadeIn(1000, function() { 
                $(this).addClass('active'); 
            });  
        return;  
        }  
        var $active = $('li.active', this);  
        var $next;  

        if($active.next().length == 0)  
            $next = $('li:first', this);  
        else  
            $next = $('li.active', this).next();  

        $active.fadeOut(1000, function() {  
            $active.removeClass('active');  
            $next.fadeIn(1000, function() {  
                $(this).addClass('active');  
            });  
        });  
    });  
}  
swapImages();  
setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);
<ul class="recipeImages">  
    <li style='display:none;'><img src='images/food.jpg' /></li>
    <li style='display:none;'><img src='images/food_cukinija.jpg' /></li>
    <li style='display:none;'><img src='images/food_hamburger.jpg' /></li>
    <li style='display:none;'><img src='images/food_sushi.jpg' /></li>  
</ul>
```

what is wrong here? it acts strange when it goes to the last LI element and there is no next element. It just stops, then first one appears and again last and etc... but until he comes to  this point

```
if($active.next().length == 0)    
    $next = $('li:first', this);
```

it works perfectly.

Ok, found the problem. It works somehow buggy when the image is in absolute position

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kUWsQ/. It continuously iterates over all list elements. So, the code you posted works fine. But if you really have a problem, then please create a http://jsfiddle.net demo yourself. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: ohh, ok, then i guess there is some problems in my css, thanks for your answer